# Hibernate IN clause showing error

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping

I have to add a string array to the IN clause.

My hibernate query looks like this,

```
                Query q = 
                    session.createQuery("from CsePrcsngGroup where CSE_SID=? and CSE_GROUP IN(:cseGrpLists)");
                q.setParameter(0, cseSid);
                q.setParameterList("cseGrpLists", cseGrpLists);
                return q.list();
```

where CsePrcsngGroup is my entity class. CSE_SID and CSE_GROUP are field Names and cseGrpLists is a string array.

I get this excpetion on execution,

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:138)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:316)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:282)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:639)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:185)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.execute_for_describe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:503)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute_maybe_describe(OracleStatement.java:1029)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.execute_maybe_describe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:535)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1126)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3001)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3043)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1849)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:718)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2294)
    ... 55 more

Wrapped exception:
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2297)
```

any suggestions? I tried using the entity names instaed of DB column names but getting the same error.Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: how you are saying error in IN clause

Comment: Turn on the logging and exam the SQL created by hibernate. Use some DBMS to run query on the same connection settings. `ORA-00942` is thrown because of that you do not have access to Oracle object. So the issue is the query output or privilege.

Answer (score 0):

use propery names insteadof column names in your query.

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from CsePrcsngGroup where property1=? and property2 IN(:cseGrpLists)");
```

like insteadof `'CSE_SID'` use his property name mapped to this column `(ex: id)`

Comment: Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist